# authorization has been denied for this request using JWT

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, owin, jwt, katana

I am trying to implement JWT authentication using OWIN middleware for my ASP.NET WebAPI 2.0.

**I am through with the first task of obtaining the jwt token** from the OAuthAuthorizationServer. The resource owner and token server are same i.e same WebAPI generates the token and should consume too to provide access to resources.

In my Global.asax file I have added the below code line

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(FilterConfig.Configure);
```

In my Filter.config I have added the following configure method which I pass above to the GlobalConfiguration.Configure method in the Global.asax file.

```
public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Filters.Add(new System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

Adding this obviously secures all the apis from unauthorized access.

When I hit any api with Bearer token passed into the Authorization header I only get the message "authorization has been denied for this request" all the time.

Now the thing that is baffling me most is that this happens when I **don't** add the below code in my OWIN startup file

```
var config = new HttpConfiguration();
WebApiConfig.Register(config);

app.UseWebApi(config);
```

As soon as I add the above code in the startup file the authorization is somehow removed. And I can hit the api which was inaccessible before. It is accessible whether I pass the bearer token or not which it must not.

Can you guys point me in right direction. If it behaves like this then what does this suggest?

**Updated**

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {

            var issuer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["issuer"];
            var secret = TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret"]);



            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(issuer)
            };


            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthOptions);

            // Enable bearer authentication with jwt
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                AllowedAudiences = new[] { "Any" },
                IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                {
                    new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer,secret)
                }
            });

            var hh = ConfigureWebApi();
            app.UseWebApi(hh);
       }


        private HttpConfiguration ConfigureWebApi()
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();
            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:50374", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                "DefaultApi",
                "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
            config.Filters.Add(new System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute());
            return config;
        }
```

Comment: If you're supposed to use owin middleware then scip the Global.asax class and bind all configuration and middlewares to the IAppBuilder instans in the owin startup class instead.

Comment: @MarcusH You mean I should remove the FilterConfig, RouteConfig, GlobalConfiguration, BundleConfig statements from Global.asax file

Comment: I just mean that the owin startup and global.asax are basically doing the same thing. Unnecessarily to use them both side by side. I would move all configuration to startup class.

Comment: @MarcusH Ok I moved it to the OWIN startup class now one thing has changed ..its now giving the unauthorized request for the api which were accessible before as explained in my question.

Comment: @MarcusH One question the webapi is on the localhost and running. I can debug it. When i hit the token api from the postman the breakpoint at GrantResourceOwnerCredentials method is hit. Which method should be hit first in case i hit other apis from the postman ?

Comment: But when you hit the api, do you pass the bearer token in the http header? This great article gave me good insite of how to configure the authentication using owin and web api 2. http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/

Comment: Yes I do, It does not make any difference. Thanks for the link. Looking into it.

Comment: Can you add your auth config code to your post?  How are you validating the token?

Comment: @StinkyTowel Sure updated. But what i can say using the examples i have seen there is no visible validating code in thr.

Comment: In **Global.asax** file to which method you added the line. ?

Comment: @Aravind I removed the Global.asax file. and moved that code line into ConfigureWebApi method in OWIN startup file. second last code line.

Comment: @MarcusH  See if you can answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058351/cant-figure-out-if-owin-is-intercepting-requests-to-api-from-client

Comment: @tariq just comment on that :)